# Determining whether viewWillDisappear is called because child modal appearance or not

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController, `ViewControllerA` that is presented as a modal view controller from a `RootViewController` class.

`ViewControllerA` then presents another modal controller class, `ModalViewControllerB` and I'd like to know whether the calls to `ViewControllerA's`

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

is due to `ModalViewControllerB` appearing on screen or because ViewControllerA is being dismissed.

Is there a built-in iOS way to figure this out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `[self isBeingDismissed]` will distinguish the two cases you're talking about.